# Swing dashboard

Tags: java, swing, dashboard

In our desktop application built on Swing we are going to implement dashboard functionality. I mean that we want something like [iGoogle](http://www.google.com/) (or Jira dashboard). We want to be able to add widgets from some predefined list to grid-based layout, maximize/restore widgets, arrange widgets with drag-n-drop and so on. We can implement it ourselves, but I'm not sure we want to reinvent the wheel. Are there any existing frameworks to solve this?

In addition to mentioned features it would be nice to have following ones:

- Different layouts (3-column, 4-column, 3-column with flexible middle, 3-column with header etc) and ability to create custom ones
- Ability to access size/position metadata from widget (i.e., maximized widget can show more info then default mode)
- Ability to increase widget size to take, say 2 columns and 3 rows instead on 1x1 by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jide Dashboard](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/download.htm) is quite good. You can see it in action in the web start demo.